# Add an item to a firebase collection

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I need to append an item in one or more collections in Firebase Database using angularfire (AngularJS)

For example, if I have:

```
users {
    Marcelo: {
        userid: 1
    },
    Javier: {
        userid: 2
    }
}
```

How can I append a new item in each collection, getting something like this?

```
users {
    Marcelo: {
        userid: 1
        state: "enabled"
    },
    Javier: {
        userid: 2
        state: "enabled"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific AngularFire operation for this. But since AngularFire is just built on top of the Firebase JavaScript SDK, you use that to [read the data and loop over it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events) and then [update each item](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields).

A short snippet to get you started:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
users.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
    userSnapshot.ref.update({ state: "enabled" });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this sample we create a `function` to insert `param` in our `object`

```
//object = users object
//key = state or something else
//value = true or something else

var insertParam = function(object, key, value) {
  for (var _key in object) {
     object[_key][key] = value;
  }
}
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", [
  "$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.users = {
      Marcelo: {
        userid: 1
      },
      Javier: {
        userid: 2
      }
    }


    var insertParam = function(object, key, value) {
      for (var _key in object) {
        object[_key][key] = value;
      }
    }

    insertParam($scope.users, "state", true);
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, option) in users">
      {{key}}
      <ul>
        <li><b>userId:</b> {{option.userid}}</li>
        <li><b>state:</b> {{option.state}}</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```